# Domino Designer - Creating response

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus, lotus-formula

I received an email notification regarding the rating of my buyer. I will need to provide a  feedback regarding her rating to me. My feedback should appear on the lower part of the original document/rating sheet. The rating part must be locked for editing to the Buyer and the feedback must be locked for editing to me (Seller). The rating and feedback must be viewable for all as a single document. And I have to do this for every buyer that will rate me. What command can I use?

Attached is the screen capture for reference.

[image: Response]

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Controlled Access Section](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_RESTRICTING_ACCESS_TO_A_SECTION.html).

Comment: Sir Richard, how can I lock some part for editing? In my example, I am the Buyer. I will input the name of the Seller, Performance, Improvement, and Recommendation. Upon clicking Save, I will send an email notification to the Seller with the copy of the Rating Form. The Seller will then reply to me and make a feedback. The feedback must appear on the original Rating Form and my Rating for the Seller must be locked only to me as rater.

Comment: Controlled access sections lock portions of the form so that only designate people can edit them. You can read about the at the link that I provided.

Answer (score 1):

Controlled access works, or simply use a combination of computed text, fields and hide-when formulas.  If you want read-only, show the computed text (whose formula is the name of the field) and hide the field.  If you want to be able to edit, hide the computed text and show the field.